# Facebook API query on /me with access token and fields only returns status=True. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

The following python code:

```
  # user profile information
  args = {
    'access_token':access_token,
    'fields':'id,name',
  }
  print 'ACCESSED', urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me', urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
```

Prints the following:

*ACCESSED {"success":true}*

The token is valid, no error, the fields are valid.  Why is it not returning the fields I asked for?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out urllib.urlopen will send the data as a POST when the data parameter is provided.  Facebook Graph API works using GET not POST.  Change the call to trick the function into calling just a URL ( no data ):

```
print 'ACCESSED', urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me/?' + urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
```

And everything works! Sigh, I can see why urllib is being altered in python 3.0...

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question, It helped me with the same issue (GET instead of POST).

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a `/` to the URL to get `https://graph.facebook.com/me/` instead of `https://graph.facebook.com/me`.

```
# user profile information
args = {
    'access_token':access_token,
    'fields':'id,name'
}

print 'ACCESSED', urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me/', urllib.urlencode(args)).read()
```

PS : Try using the `requests` which is much more efficient than `urllib`, here is the doc : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: I changed the URL to include the tailing / and still same status=true result without requested fields.

Comment: I've just been testing that code snippet and it's working for me !